# Teams: How to open Task Module from Adaptive Card in desktop app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am sending an adaptive card to teams with the bot framework. That is working fine. The card should contain an action that opens a task module like explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots?tabs=nodejs#the-flexibility-of-tasksubmit).

My code for the card looks like this:

```
AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 3))
        {
            Body = new List<AdaptiveElement>() {
                new AdaptiveTextBlock() {
                    Wrap = true,
                    Text = "test",
                    IsSubtle = false,
                    Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Large,
                    Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder
                }
            },
            Actions = new List<AdaptiveAction>() {
                new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
                {
                    Title = "In Teams",
                    DataJson = $"{{\"msteams\":{{\"type\":\"task/fetch\"}},\"Url\":\"{url}\",\"Title\": \"{title}\"}}"
                }
            }
        };
```

The card is showing in teams, but the button is not working in the desktop client. It is just showing this message in red:

> Something went wrong. Please try again.

In the web version the task module is just opening fine. Do I have to change something for the desktop version of teams? Tried to change my code a bit like in [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/448c5535cb6d6be8d7a61f78ef1902b55c1f0edb/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module) but that isn't working either.

**Update**:
So I tried the example and it did work one time. After that I had the same error message and no task module is showing. But when I pop out the App in a new window, everything is working fine. So it looks to me like a bug in teams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the message “Something went wrong. Try again.", when called Task Module from adaptive card. I installed the bot through a local upload of the manifest, but then I found out that it was also added to the list of applications for our organization, and apparently there was some kind of collision between them. After I uninstalled the application from my desktop Teams and installed it from the application pool - the error disappeared.

Comment: We are going to try that. We are currently running an older version of the App in oour tenant and I am just side loading the app.

Comment: I marked your answer as solution. Its more like a workaround since its obviously a  bug in Teams. Makes it really hard to test a new version of the app with only a few people in the "live" tenant.

Comment: Following the answer certainly made this error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This might relate to how the platform is reading your json - the "" characters for example might not be handled properly on the desktop. To solve this, rather leave the json conversion up to the platform and, for your example in C#, create a strong type instead. The example you link to does exactly that - see this line:

```
new TaskModuleAction(cardType.ButtonTitle, new CardTaskFetchValue<string>() { Data = cardType.Id }
```

inside https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/448c5535cb6d6be8d7a61f78ef1902b55c1f0edb/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module/Bots/TeamsTaskModuleBot.cs, which is referencing this class: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/901bc140f5aa300fbfa852e64afd7c65fceebff9/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module/Models/AdaptiveCardTaskFetchValue.cs

Comment: Tried that. Even updated all the packages to the same version as in the example. The cards are showing up in teams as before. But no success with the event...its not even sending to the bot.

Comment: So I just tested the whole example and after one time working it just stopped working and resulted in the same behavior as in my app. When I pop out the app from the main window, everything is working fine. But that is not an acceptable behavior. Looks like a MS Teams bug for me.

Comment: We are not able to repro your issue.